# Override a Doctrine entity class in a vendor library to remove an entity property

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

Is it possible to extends an entity from a library that exists in vendor to remove a property from an entity?

IE:

vendor/someLibrary/entity/Car.php

- id
- colour
- List item
- wheelCount
- fuel
- List item

But I want to extend Car.php to remove the fuel property because we now live in a world where cars don’t need fuel